# Sticky posts are not showing at the top of category posts

Tags: wp-query, loop

Can anyone tell me why sticky posts are not being displayed at the top of the following query:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'posts_per_page'=>10,
 'category__in'=>array( 5,140,430 ) 
));
```

It was working fine until I added the `'category__in'=>array( 5,140,430 )` parameter, but the stick posts are in category 430 so I don't see why they would suddenly stop appearing at the top?

Edit: This appears to be a [long-standing wordpress issue](https://www.google.com/#q=category__in+and+stick+posts) between `category__in` and sticky posts. Wordpress codex says stickies should always appear on the front page, but seeing as how this is on the front page and doesn't work it must be a bug.

Comment: What is $blog_order?

Comment: `DESC` and also irrelevant in the sense that if you take it out you get the same result. There appears to be a conflict between `category__in` and sticky posts.

Comment: Was just wondering. You should always add all relevant info to your question

Comment: Add that edit as an answer and accept it. You can score yourself some reputation

Comment: I'm not concerned with reputation. I'm concerned with solving the problem and offering future users workarounds. I've accepted Nabha's workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have direct experience with this, but from what I read...

Sticky posts don't show up by default on category pages, so adding the categories may throw the query into an "I don't care about sticky posts" mode.

You could try running a query first that just grabs the sticky posts, using arguments like this:

```
    $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
    $args = array(
        'post__in'  => $sticky,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
    );
```

You may be able to include `category__in` there as well, to get only sticky posts from the categories you want. Again, I haven't tried it, but it's a good avenue of approach.

More information:

- [Sticky Posts Not Sticking to Top of Category Archive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117279/sticky-posts-not-sticking-to-top-of-category-archive)
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be a long-standing issue / bug between `category__in` and stick posts. I'd venture it's a bug because wordpress docs say stickies should always work on the front page but this is not the case. https://www.google.com/#q=category__in+and+stick+posts

Comment: I'm accepting this as an answer because it offers a workaround to the bug.